# Using a CSS Transition to slide a div in on load

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

so I have this div that slides in on load, but for some reason I can't seem to get the action to actually fire off, can someone help me?

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div class="right-scroll-content" id="right-scroll-slide">aaaa</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #right-scroll-slide{
    -webkit-transition:all 1s;
    -ms-transition:all 1s;
    -moz-transition:all 1s;
    -o-transition:all 1s
        position:absolute;
        top:-100px;
        background:red;
    }
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("right-scroll-slide").style.top="70px";
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qrvp58Ly/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missed a `;` after `-o-transition` there **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eter5cLv/)**

Comment: Wow, I've been such an air head lately! Sometimes I just need a 2nd set of eyes on the error! thanks man! Enjoy your easy rep :D